# UITabBar custom background image applied in one view controller instead of in the AppDelegate

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbar, uiappearance

I am working with themes in my iPhone app. I have two tabs in a tab bar (Timeline and Settings) and when the user goes to the second tab (Settings), selects themes in the settings and selects a theme, this styles the background image and the navigation bar of the first table view controller in the first tab (Timeline). This works.

I want to achieve the same thing with the tab bar, so the tab bar changes along with the background image and the navigation bar.

In my timeline table view, I put the following code in the viewWillAppear:

```
UIImage *tabBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Purplepinktopp.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBackgroundImage];
```

However, the tab bar never changes. The only way to change the tab bar is in the AppDelegate but that then changes it everywhere. I need to allow the user to select a theme and it changes accordingly and so I need to change this on a per view controller basis, exactly the same way with the navigation bar.

In the viewWillAppear of this timeline table view, I set the navigation bar with:

```
UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Purplepinknav.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

That always works. This doesn't work for the Tab Bar however with the code above.

Edit: I've added the apperanceWhenContainedIn to the viewWillAppear:

```
UIImage *tabBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SolidPurple.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBackgroundImage];

[UITabBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITabBar class], [UITabBar class], nil];
```

But that doesn't seem to be doing anything.

How can I go about fixing this? Any assistance would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a refinement to the UIAppearance proxy call you could try...

```
+ (id)appearanceWhenContainedIn:(Class <UIAppearanceContainer>)ContainerClass,...
```

This sets the appearance for a UIAppearance Proxy compliant object to the supplied values only when it's contained in a specific view controller subclass.

Comment: Thanks very much @Cocoadelica - that's really helpful. That looks very interesting. Please can I ask how exactly I would apply that to my viewWillAppear for the tab bar?

Comment: I've added the code (and updated the question here) but just can't seem to find a way to get this working. Your thoughts on this would be really appreciated and I thank you for taking the time to reply

Comment: I've fixed this with         UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"purplytab.png"]
                                  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
        [self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];

Many thanks for your help on this. Really appreciate it!